# how to check occurance of string across two or more columns for each row and assign the final column with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, numpy

```
id.       datcol1       datacol2  datacol-n       final col(to be created in output)
                                                                 
1           false       true         true          0
2           false        false       false             2
3           true         true        true          0
4           true        false        false            1
```

there are multiple columns say 13,
So the job is to take each row id across all the column and
check if the columns have atleast or equalto  two "true" strings then assign   0 ; and if one "true "string then assign 1, if no "true" at all then assign 2

Comment: The provided output doesn't match your logic

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to change the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering df to be:

```
In [1542]: df
Out[1542]: 
   id.  datcol1  datacol2  datacol-n
0    1    False      True       True
1    2    False     False      False
2    3     True      True       True
3    4     True     False      False
```

Use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), [`df.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html), [`Series.ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and [`df.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
In [1546]: import numpy as np

In [1547]: x = df.filter(like='dat').sum(1)

In [1548]: conds = [x.ge(2), x.eq(1), x.eq(0)]

In [1549]: choices = [0, 1, 2]

In [1553]: df['flag'] = np.select(conds, choices)

In [1554]: df
Out[1554]: 
   id.  datcol1  datacol2  datacol-n  flag
0    1    False      True       True     0
1    2    False     False      False     2
2    3     True      True       True     0
3    4     True     False      False     1
```

Comment: I am actually trying to count the number of true and make the decision to score it

Comment: @user10057386 Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Done that, in line 1547 , y do u use sum? apart from the point to get the x in array list format

Comment: @user10057386 That `sum` is to sum the number of `True` values.